# Not turning off completely the system. its going to the halt mode in Fedora

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora, shutdown

some time when i want to shutdown the system in fedora, the system not shutdown completely.
in this problem screen is off but fan is working

Not sure if this is relevant,but there are several errors in the journal system journalctl:

```
fedora systemd-coredump[12699]: Failed to connect to coredump service: Connection refused

fedora systemd[1]: udisks2.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
fedora systemd[1]: udisks2.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

OS:
fedora 37

The system should be turned off completely, which does not happen, and the laptop fan is still on

Comment: Yes, it's relevant. You have an unstable system, it crashes here and there. So no surprises you have the outcome like observed.

Comment: @0andriy how can i fix it? Is this related to hardware issues?